# Multiple Bluetooth speakers with Multiple Raspberry Pi’s

Tags: audio, bluetooth, speakers

I want to be able to connect multiple Bluetooth speakers to raspberry pi’s, with two different inputs. My end goal is to have a Sonos-like system, where all the speakers are playing in sync.

Inputs:

1. 3.5mm input audio (Microphone, Optional)
2. Bluetooth or AirPlay audio input or Wire

Outputs:

Two Bluetooth speakers (But I want the ability to be able to add more in the future).

Here is few ways I was thinking:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I currently have a Pi 4, and would like to know how I would set this system up, and what other models would be best to buy. Everything will be on the same Wi-Fi network.

I found this: [github.com/balenalabs/balena-sound](https://github.com/balenalabs/balena-sound). But it only looks like the speaker can be connected by wire, not Bluetooth.

In case it already is not obvious, I am a beginner to this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: How would you accommodate all the transmission delays to keep them in sync?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Chenmunka I’m not sure. If I knew how, I would have stated it. 

Community, I’m not sure what you mean. The issue is that I have two inputs and two outputs, and want to know how to link it all together.

Comment: @jostola, I am aware of what the Community is, I was just adding my response so others can find it. I edited the question, hope it is more clear now.

Comment: yes, it is now clear

Comment: Balena Sound offers something similar, have a go at it.. https://sound.balenalabs.io/